# QueryDsl doesn't generate Q class using Spring Boot and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, querydsl

I don't know why but I can't generate the query class using spring boot and query dsl.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency> 
            <!-- Joda-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

I aslo add to the build path the generated folder, but it is empty.
Did I forget any configuration for query dsl?

Comment: May I know why you aren't excluding `querydsl-apt` from `com.mysema.maven` plugin?

Comment: Also, frequently do project refresh as eclipse caches the fiesystem and we miss to identify

Comment: why do I have to exclude  querydsl-apt from com.mysema.maven plugin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QUwU19ep is my pom. I followed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/rest/starbucks/pom.xml

Comment: @harshavmb thank you! I fiound the problem.. I was using the wrong processor

Comment: Happy to see that it helped you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was using the wrong processor, I have to use `com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor`  instead of `com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor`

So this is the entire plugin :

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor` also works for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-common-model</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <!--
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java/com/uniarb/autogds/dao/entity</sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    -->
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                <processors>
                    <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
                <options>
                    <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                    <querydsl.createDefaultVariable>true</querydsl.createDefaultVariable>
                    <querydsl.packageSuffix>.apt</querydsl.packageSuffix>
                </options>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case I had to add `<classifier>jakarta</classifier>` to the dependencies of querydsl. Then I could find generated classes in `target/generated-sources`

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
```